# Issue with Angular $location html5Mode within an existing application that cannot change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

All,

I am developing an Angular app (not my first) within an existing JavaScript application that is primarily based in jQuery and Django templates.

In order to get to my Angular application from within the existing application, the URL will look like this:

```
/existing-application/#myapp/myapp
```

I realized early that I would have to avoid the injection of $location anywhere in my application or else have Angular become utterly confused with the existing # (hashtag) in the URL.

I have reached a point where this is no longer an option.  Therefore, I am setting `html5Mode: true` and am working with the `<base href="" />` header tag to try and find a solution.

However, the closest I have come to having this approach working results in a URL that looks like this after my page renders:

```
/existing-application/#myapp%2Fmyapp
```

I currently have a base tag of:

```
<base href="/existing-application/#myapp/myapp" />
```

This will load the Angular app. successfully but the URL is then rewritten automatically to:

```
/existing-application/#myapp%2Fmyapp
```

Which causes all sorts of problems within and outside of my Angular application.

I have read some reports of bugs wherein there is an issue with $location.rewrite that causes the trailing '/' to become escaped.

I have attempted to work around this issue in several ways, from modifying the `<base />` tag, calling `$location.path('/existing-application/#myapp/myapp)` on page load, using `$routeProvider`, changing the `hashPrefix`, and it seems the closest I can ever come to is the escaped trailing slash.

Changing the hashPrefix to '!' merely resulted in:

```
/existing-application/#!#myapp/myapp
```

Any advice on what to try next?  I am not opposed to not using html5Mode, but without doing so I don't believe this approach will ever work.

Thank you.

Config Block:

```
.config(['$locationProvider', '$interpolateProvider', '$websocketProvider', 
             function($locationProvider, $interpolateProvider, $websocketProvider) {

        // inject meta 'base' href into <head> tag
        $('head').append('<base href="/existing-application/#myapp/myapp" />');

        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{$');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('$}');

        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
              enabled: true,
              rewriteLinks: false,
              requireBase: true
            });
```

Angular Information:
 Angular v. 1.3.1

Comment: How does your config block look? Did you try to do the same thing with [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)?

Comment: Dan, this is *one* iteration that produces the current behavior.
`.config(['$locationProvider', '$interpolateProvider', '$websocketProvider', 
          function($locationProvider, $interpolateProvider, $websocketProvider) {
  
  // inject meta 'base' href into <head> tag
  $('head').append('<base href="/existing-application/#myapp/myapp" />');

  
  
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{$');
     $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('$}');
     
     $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        rewriteLinks: false,
        requireBase: true
      });`

Comment: How about placing the `<base href>` in the run block?

Comment: Dan - Tried that as well, no luck.  Pretty sure the <base> tag is taking affect; main problem is existing application's routing system, which if it sees something it doesn't like, it tries to redirect.